# How do I pass multiple variables to function within PHP statement?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Trying to call function `Sel_item` and pass it the `fieldname1` variable as well as the `id`.  The passing of the `id` works fine, but as soon as I try to pass the `fieldname1`, it dies.  Basically trying to pass the `id` and the `name of the person` in mysql database to another function.

```php
$id = $row["id"];
$fieldname1 = $row["person_name"];
$fieldname2 = $row["check_in_butt"];
$fieldname3 = $row["date_time"];
$str = "";
if($fieldname2 == true) $str = "checked";
 
echo '<tr> 
  <td>'.$fieldname1.'</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"'.$str. 'onclick="Sel_item('.$id.,.$fieldname1.')" </td>
```

Comment: `Sel_item` is a php or javascript function ??

Comment: The comma between `$id.,.$fieldname1` should be in quotes. Should be: `<td><input type="checkbox" '. $str . ' onclick="Sel_item('. $id .','. $fieldname1 .')"></td>';`

Comment: @GNassro it is a javascript function being called within a php statement.  
https://pastebin.com/7P7Tzr6G

This is the whole thing for context.

Comment: the answer of Abdullah look good, you must check the console of the browser , maybe you have some error in your JavaScript function

Answer (score 1):

I usually make it like this. Work for me

```
<?php
$id = $row["id"];
$fieldname1 = $row["person_name"];
$fieldname2 = $row["check_in_butt"];
$fieldname3 = $row["date_time"];
$str = "";
if($fieldname2 == true) $str = "checked";
?>

<tr> 
    <td><?= $fieldname1 ?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" <?= $str ?> onclick="Sel_item('<?= $id ?>', '<?= $fieldname1 ?>')"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Still isn't working...I made a pastebin with the whole project  https://pastebin.com/7P7Tzr6G.  This is my first time trying to code javascript / php...I built the whole thing in HTML but I realized later the need to save things to a database required more than HTML.  :-\

Comment: may I know which database you are using, so that I can check it as a whole

Comment: I am using mysql database